# How is audio streamed using HTTP

Tags: html, http, audio

I am dealing with a legacy podcasting service and it seems like a good time to take advantage of HTML5 instead.  Our users access this service from our website, and it would be nice if these anonymous users have a seamless experience with our transition.  I am planning on using [Media Element](http://mediaelementjs.com/).

I'm worried about what I don't know... seems like everything.  Is it ok to use this forum to ask for background information?

It's not even clear about the definition of "Streaming Media".  Some people specifically use the term to refer to a live broadcast of non-persistent data. Our podcasting service uses static MP3 files.  So its significant value is coercing the client to "play" the data as it downloads.  What is the magic in the background that accomplishes this desired client behavior?

I just noticed that Firefox now performs this magic automatically.  Why did it take 20 years to add this rather obvious feature?

The biggest difference between streaming static data and traditional data transfer is the ability to seek:  If I combine 10 music tracks into a single playlist file (an album to my old-school thinking) then the user should be able to jump ahead to the last track without the intervening data.  This requires a request, issued midstream, that changes the original response.  These mechanics have nothing to do with HTML (as in HTML5).  I would guess that Flash, RealAudio, etc, must've created proprietary extensions to HTTP in addition to any proprietary codecs.  How can HTML5 standardize media streaming without a corresponding upgrade to the HTTP standard?

I feel a little bit like Peter Higgs defining the properties of a hypothetical boson.  Obviously there are protocols to handle the requests/responses necessary to accomplish this form of streaming. But since I can't even confirm their existence, it seems speculative to ask questions about server operation.  Nevertheless, it seems like a leap of faith that an HTML5 compliant browser is somehow going to be compatible with my legacy server.

Should be simple.  What am I missing?

Thanks!
Jim

Comment: I think my observation is wrong that Firefox "performs this magic automatically".  This sudden behavior was not due to a recent Firefox upgrade.  It seems the phenomenon was triggered because Firefox found the 80M mp3 in its cache.  Firefox works the way it always has- downloading the file entirely before playing it.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that "Streaming Media" is a bit of an overloaded term. I tend to think that the vast majority of streaming media content is delivered via vanilla HTTP requests.

*"I just noticed that Firefox now performs this magic automatically. Why did it take 20 years to add this rather obvious feature?"*

I think that many browsers have had the capability to play at least simple audio formats natively for sometime (I think versions of Netscape from 1995 would handle some plain PCM WAV, AIFF, and SND files). About being able to handle MP3 natively, there were longstanding legal, licensing, and patent battles that are still in process. That adds to the friction. By now, I think most of the major browsers can handle MP3 audio natively via the audio tag.

Regarding seeking: A sufficiently intelligent client can do that via plain HTTP. If the user issues a seek request and the portion has not been downloaded yet, the client could close the HTTP connection, create a new one, and request a certain range of bytes. And that's only if the entire file hasn't been downloaded already. It's possible that Media Element already does something like this.

In your playlist example, the 10 tracks should be separate files, rather than squashed together into one big file. Once playback finished on the first track, the JavaScript can receive a signal that tells it to update the UI and request the second file for playback. If the user elects to skip to track 10 while playing track 1, then the client just requests track 10.

I hope I've helped. I know the feeling you're expressing-- not sure about the right question to ask in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for responding to this languishing questions

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to answer my own question.  Maybe the best I can do is disqualify any ridiculous speculations.

Summary of my original post:

1. What is the magic in the background that accomplishes this desired client behavior (processing multimedia data on the fly)?
2. What changed in Firefox so that it now plays MP3 audio "on the fly"?
3. What protocol is used to accomplish streaming over HTTP?

Based on how I understand **Multimedia Mike's** answer, the browser processes data "on the fly" if it can access an appropriate codec.  So the answer to Q1 is to provide a plugin client, such as FlashPlayer or SilverStream, that includes a codec.  In other words, everything boils down to codecs that are either proprietary or open.  Similarly, Q2's answer is that, to comply with HTML5, Firefox now includes (by crook or hook) an MP3 codec.

**Multimedia Mike's** suggestion to load playlist tracks as separate files doesn't specifically answer the question about the underlying protocol.  In my particular project, discreet seeks would be a functional downgrade, and probably not acceptable.

I'm currently under the assumption that while handling a seek request, clients inelegantly sever their connections at the TCP level.  And then simply issue a new request that specificies "HTTP Range".  Anecdotedly, this explanation is consistent with the clunky and unreliable responses I experience.  While a few conversations with other programmers have been lively enough, I still don't have an authoritative answer.

Comment: Meta: It's best to either edit your original question (and perhaps add a comment to my answer which will notify me of the update); or post a separate follow-up question (tag it similarly).

Comment: iOS "Live Streaming" breaks the media into lots of smaller chunks so they can be delivered by any old web server.  Lots of detail here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/Introduction/Introduction.html AFAIK this is not applicable to non-apple platforms, but note that it is *required* behavior for iOS apps using mobile networks.  I'm not sure if that counts for audio or just video.

Comment: Thanks for responding Dan.  Your answer makes sense: If the chunks are small enough, then a seek request could just flush the buffer, instead of breaking a connection.  But this implies an even more reliable protocol, because the client needs to continually issue new requests to keep filling the buffer.

Comment: I've been playing with WireShark and have some definitive info that I will post separately.

Answer (score -1):

The most generic application I can think of is the Flash Player in YouTube.  I used [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to examine the HTTP requests.  Unexpectedly, everything is passed as URL search arguments instead of HTTP headers.  Here is a list of the arguments:

- source
- ipbits
- ip
- cpn
- range
- mv
- ratebypass
- newshard
- key
- factor
- mt
- ms
- keepalive
- id
- fexp
- algorithm
- burst
- sparams
- cp
- sver
- itag
- signature
- upn
- expire

For all packets examined:

```
burst=40
algorithm=throttle-factor
```

Only the range argument seems to vary from request to request:

```
range=13-1781759
range=1781760-3563519
range=3563520-5345279
range=5345280-7127039
range=7127040-8908799
```

To summarize, these findings seem consistent with everything that's been discussed in this thread.  So while I understand that this protocol is a proprietary extension written by the company that owns flash, HTML 5 is supposed to create a standardized replacement.  I'm still hoping someone will answer the basic question:  What is the underlying protocol that emulates these features of Flash?  Possibly, HTML5 will not incorporate all these features.  But that answer is important, too.

-Jim

Comment: Much more discussion occured on the icecast forum:  http://icecast.imux.net/viewtopic.php?t=8009